# Why do jetty Handlers have setServer?

Tags: java, jetty

Why does Jetty's `Handler` interface have `getServer` and `setServer`?

How do the various in-built `Handler` implementations use the value provided to `setServer`?

Is it safe to associate the same `Handler` to multiple `Server` instances listening on different ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlers use the server reference for a variety of reasons - accessing common resources like thread pools & login services, or looking for other contexts to dispatch requests to.

It is not possible to have the same handler in more than one server.

However, a server can have more than 1 connector, so you can still have many ports for each handler.